# Find differences in a .po file

Tags: localization, diff, gettext, po

I have a .po file where most translated strings are identical to original ones. However, few are different. How do I quickly find the ones that differ from original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [podiff](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/podiff/)

I used it, an it workd for me. Its in C, so you have to compile it. make is your friend

Comment: with git 2.3.2, I manage to make it work with `command = /usr/bin/podiff` (without `−D−u −L` options as mentionned in the git example), otherwise it tells "wrong number of arguments"

Comment: It doesn't seem to support message wrapping in multiple lines. I'm getting "digikam.po:192: syntax error".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the many web-based localization management platforms. To name a few:

- [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) (disclaimer: my company builds this product)
- [Web Translate It](http://webtranslateit.com/)
- [Transifex](http://www.transifex.net/)
- [GetLocalization](http://www.getlocalization.com/)

This kind of platforms allows you to keep your resource files in sync, edit them in a web-based editor (useful for no-technical translators) and most importantly to highlight/see only the changed/untranslated strings.